# Makefile problems

Tags: c++, makefile

I want compile makefile in linux. 
This Is my makefile

```
FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
libavformat                        \
libavfilter                        \
libavcodec                         \
libswresample                      \
libswscale                         \
libavutil                          \

LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS))
LIBS = -lstdc++fs
PROJECT_ROOT    =   $(shell pwd)

CXX        = g++
CXXFLAGS   = -c -Wall
STRIP      = strip
LDFLAGS    = 
OBJS       = main.o chekfiletoconcat.o
DEPS       = chekfiletoconcat.h 
EXECUTABLE = concat

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)
    $(STRIP) $(EXECUTABLE)

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $<


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

But I recive error ** make: *** No rule to make target '-lstdc++fs', needed by 'all'.  Stop.**

Answer (score 2):

This line, the rule for `all`:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)
```

translates into:

```
all: concat -lstdc++fs
```

and that's what's causing the error, since `make` doesn't know how to build `-lstdc++fs` - it is, after all, a compiler/linker *argument* rather than a file.

I don't think the `$(LIBS)` should be there, it makes much more sense to have:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS) $(LIBS)
    $(STRIP) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

In other words, use `$(LIBS)` flags to compile the executable, but *not* as a dependency.

Comment: But hot to connect -lstdc++fs

Comment: @Orest in the `$(EXECUTABLE)` target, pass the `$(LIBS)` flag to the linker

Answer (score 1):

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)
```

It makes no sense to have dependencies to your libs as long you do not build it by yourself. In your case, `$(LIBS)` did *not* contain the name of the library files, which is necessary to make a build rule from it and make it possible to make them a prerequisite, but directly have the "-lxyz" command line option for the linker. You can't use this format for deps in Makefile. In your case, I would simply remove the `$(LIBS)` from your rule.

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: But hot to connect -lstdc++fs

Comment: @Orest hot->how? :-) Only remove $(LIBS) from `all: $(EXECUTABLE) $(LIBS)` The line `(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDLIBS)` will persist and that will link the needed libs

Comment: I resive this error  **undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::temp_directory_path** -lstdc++fs need for std::experimental::filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I have done this

```
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) -lstdc++fs
```

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```